Discussing $a \oplus_g x = x, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ for $a \oplus_g b = g^{-1}(g(a) \cdot g(b))$ and $g$ bijective with no fixed points.
I recently came across the following exercise related to elementary function theory.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bijective function without fixed points (that is, there does not exist $u \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(u) = u$). Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, we define $a \oplus_g b$ as follows:
$$
a \oplus_g b = g^{-1}(g(a) \cdot g(b)).
$$
Suppose hypothetically that there exists a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with the following property: For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $a \oplus_g x = x$.
Regarding this, it is CORRECT to state that:
(a) $x = g(1)$.
(b) $x = g^{-1}(1)$.
(c) $x = 1$.
(d) there is no such $x$.
(e) there are infinitely many real numbers with this property.

My thought process was as follows. First, since $$ is bijective, it is invertible. Therefore, by applying the function $$ to both sides of the equation, we have the following:
\begin{align*}
a \oplus_g x &= x\\
g^{-1}(g(a) \cdot g(x)) &= x\\
g\left(g^{-1}(g(a) \cdot g(x))\right) &= g(x)\\
g(a) \cdot g(x) &= g(x).
\end{align*}
But then, I could not have $g(a)=1$ because if it is for any real $a$, $g$ would no longer be bijective, right? Thus, I could conclude that no such real $x$ exists. But then, the official answer for this exercise was B, $x = g^{-1}(1)$.
I could not understand why.

Note that
$$
g(a)g(x)=g(x) \implies [g(a)-1]g(x)=0 \implies g(a)=1 \text{ or } g(x)=0.
$$
As you said, it cannot happen that $g(a)=1$, since this must be hold for all $a \in \Bbb R$.
So, $g(x)=0$, and then $x=g^{-1}(0)$ is the correct answer.
